# Untracked files on Git Repository

Tags: git

When I run "git status" I see a folder which is under untracked files. I don't want to commit this, I don't really want to do anything with it. How can I remove that message. I do not want to commit this file because someone else has already made changes to this file which I do not want to override.

Comment: Start by pulling the changes that other person made.

Comment: I cannot even switch branches. Git says that the untracked files will be overriden. Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.

Comment: You can to do 'git stash' and 'git stash pop' after switching branch

Answer (score 0):

This is the purpose of the `.gitignore` file. Create a `.gitignore` file that contains:

```
folder_name/
```

and Git will not list that folder in the list of untracked files.

Comment: I do want that file later in the process. I just don't want to commit it right now.

Comment: What will that do once the other person that has "already made changes to this file" will add it to the repo?

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. You asked how to remove that message; the above is one way to remove that message. This neither prevents nor facilitates anything you (or your coworkers) might want to do with the files later.

Comment: I just want to ignore it. Switch the branch. Get the latest which the other person has already done.

Comment: Then just delete the file.

Comment: Oh, now you reveal the *actual* problem. You can't switch branches because somebody else has added that to the repo. Rename your folder to something else, switch branches, and then decide what to do with your renamed files.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna keep this folder on git, you can't insert this folder on .gitignore file.

You can use this command:

```
git checkout your_folder/*
```

or

```
git checkout your_folder/
```

when you use `git checkout` all your changes on the file or folder since the last commit are lost.